# How to search and push new array into recursive multidimensional array in javascript (tree like structure)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a multi dimensional array like the following

```
data = [
    {
      name: "C Drive",
      subfolders: [
          {
            name: "User",
            subfolders: [
              { name: 'local_user',
              subfolders: [
              ]}
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      name: "D",
      subfolders: [
        {
          name: "Games",
          subfolders: [
              {
                name: "User Files",
                subfolders: []
              },
              {
                name: "Users",
                subfolders: []
              }
            ]
        }
  ]
}
];
```

I am also provided with a path array ['C Drive', 'User'].

I want to create a function which would take the path and add a new object to the 'subfolders' of the give path like

addChild(['C Drive', 'User'],{name: 'new_folder', subfolders: []}) should return

```
[
    {
      name: "C Drive",
      subfolders: [
          {
            name: "User",
            subfolders: [
              { name: 'local_user',
              subfolders: [
              ]},
                 { name: 'new_folder',
              subfolders: [
              ]}

            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      name: "D",
      subfolders: [
        {
          name: "Games",
          subfolders: [
              {
                name: "User Files",
                subfolders: []
              },
              {
                name: "Users",
                subfolders: []
              }
            ]
        }
  ]
}
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing a recursive search.

My snippet does this and iterates over the `route` that's given.

```js
data = [{
    name: "C Drive",
    subfolders: [{
      name: "User",
      subfolders: [{
        name: 'local_user',
        subfolders: []
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    subfolders: [{
      name: "Games",
      subfolders: [{
          name: "User Files",
          subfolders: []
        },
        {
          name: "Users",
          subfolders: []
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];

function traverseTree(route, data) {
  const r = 0
  const findParentNode = (folder, r) => {
    if (r < route.length - 1) {
      const f = folder.find(e => e.name === route[r])
      r++
      return findParentNode(f.subfolders, r)
    } else {
      return folder.find(e => e.name === route[r])
    }
  }
  return findParentNode(data, r)
}

// I suggest to pass the data array in the function
const addChild = (route, newNode, data) => {
  // you should check for the existence of the subfolders array
  return traverseTree(route, data).subfolders.push(newNode)
}

const route1 = ['C Drive', 'User']
const route2 = ['D', 'Games', 'Users']

addChild(route1, {
  name: 'new_folder',
  subfolders: []
}, data)
console.log('first:', data) // after adding node to 'C Drive -> User'

addChild(route2, {
  name: 'new_folder2',
  subfolders: []
}, data)
console.log('second:', data) // after adding node to 'D -> Games -> Users'
```